# Get field value from another window in wpf (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, window, field

I want to cary my software that I developed in C# winform to WPF base on MVVM pattern. I'm just at the beginning and there are many problems to solve.

One of them is retrieving data from other window.

In Winform i used below codes thats works fine.

This is main form :

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string userName = string.Empty;
        string userSurName = string.Empty;
        string userAddress = string.Empty;
        private void GetUserInfos()
        {
            using (var form = new UserInfosForm())
            {
                var dialog = form.ShowDialog();
                if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.userName = form.userName;
                    this.userSurName = form.userSurName;
                    this.userAddress = form.userAddress;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the form which i want to retrieve datas from:

```
public partial class UserInfosForm : Form
    {
        public string userName = string.Empty;
        public string userSurName = string.Empty;
        public string userAddress = string.Empty;

        public UserInfosForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            buttonOk.Click += ButtonOk_Click;
        }

        private void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            userName = textBoxName.Text;
            userSurName = textBoxSurName.Text;
            userAddress = textBoxAddress.Text;
        }
    }
```

How can i achieve that functionality in WPF MVVM pattern ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general in WPF and MVVM, you do that via ViewModels.

Let's say You have `MainWindow` with `MainWindowViewModel`.

On MainWindow You have a `Button`, that Command property is binded to `OpenNewWindowCommand` on `MainWindowViewModel`.

All that Command do, is showing new Window on which you enter some data, like mentioned User Name etc.

To show new Window and retrieve data from that new Window you can use this snippet

```
var view = new NewWindow();
var vm = new NewWindowVM();
view.DataContext = vm;

if (view.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false))
{
    this.UserName = vm.UserName;
}
view.Close();
```

And of course you need to use `Properties` instead of `Fields` in the ViewModels, and ViewModels needs to implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 1):

***I want to cary my software that I developed in C# winform to WPF base on MVVM pattern.***

You should first learn WPF, XAML, MVVM in order to achieve anything because you are not working on a small task but on a full project you want to port to WPF.

Anyone can give you some clues but in short you need to know that all your controls(their properties) in View(same as WinForm and it has code behind) should be defined in View Model of the same View(so, do not define it in code behind even though that exist as I said but you will not work in MVVM fashion) where finally you need to learn how to bind a datacontext from View Model to a View and if needed a single value and similar to that.

So, define your values in View Model as properties and do binding in the View in the same controls.

```
propful string userName;
propful string userSurName;
propful string userAddress;
```

but with implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private string userName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set
        {
            userName = value;
            // Notify the framework that the property has changed
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserName));
        }
    }
}
```

You don’t need click event to get values from your text box contols because they will be automatically set if you do something like this in XAML(your View).

```
<TextBox x:Name=“userName” Text="{Binding UserName}" />
```

Finally, if you want whole View, you need to do something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create a new ViewModel or view instance
        SomeViewModel newViewModel = new SomeViewModel();

        // Set the DataContext to the new instance
        this.DataContext = newViewModel;
    }
}
```

You will see how it works but again this is a raw answer for a small task(let’s call it like that) because you are going to work on whole solution(port it to new platform in .net enviroment) where your keywords are the following - contol properties values `binding` in wpf, `datacontext`, `View` and `View Model`(that is `MVVM` - Model View View Model pattern), `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and much, much more.

Comment: First of all, many thanx for your informative and detailed answer. 
Of course, I have some idea about wpf, mvvm, datacontext etc. 
I reviewed many sources and watched videos on these subject.
But sometimes, no matter how many tutorials you examine, you can not understand until you see an example solution.

Comment: Check Thomas Claudius Huber and his pluralsight videos and besides him Brian Noyes and Brian Lagunas.

Comment: thanx for advice.I will take a look right away.